# Changing Mirroring RAID disks - HP DL380

Tags: raid, hp, mirroring

I have a DL380 server with raid configured as mirroring with only two harddisks ( 0 and 1)

As we lost some files due to a software bug I removed both the HD's ( 0 and 1).

Instead I put an old harddisk which was like backup into slot 0 and started the PC but it didn't start as the backup harddisk was originally for slot 1.

So i put it in slot 1 and it started and all is fine.

Now I have a blank new harddisk, if I put it in slot 0 will it rebuild from slot 1 ?

Or will it copy from slot 0 to slot 1 and both disks will be blank ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a RAID system will write meta data on the disk to identify what it is part of (there are some systems that do that only in the controller's EEPROM, but that's rare). So regardless of the bay location of the remaining disk, it will bring up the array it expects using all its disks that are still present. Empty disks are ignored, or perhaps automatically added.

However, if your empty disk is actually not 100% empty, but also has RAID meta data on it, you may have a problem.

Also, it might not rebuild automatically. You may have to use some tool, or boot the server into the RAID setup with some F-key.

Comment: My disk is completely new so I assume there is no metadata on it. As for rebuilding the HP systems do it automatically. But generally it copies from Slot 0 to Slot 1. This is what I am afraid of. If it copies the blank disk from Slot 1 to the data disk on Slot 0, I will lose all the data.

Comment: @HuzefaAkhter How do you know it copies like that? You would not be the first person whose disk0 is broken. It would be very unusual to have to put disk 1 in slot 0 before replacing a disk.

Comment: My both disks are broken, and when putting the backup disk (3 months old) into slot 0 , the server won't start. When I put the backup disk in Slot 1 the server starts, so that is what I did, now I want to put a blank disk in the Slot 0 for backup.

Comment: @HuzefaAkhter but does that say anything about which direction it syncs? To me, it just says something about it not supporting switching around RAID members.

Comment: Then should I take the risk and insert a blank disk ?

Comment: @HuzefaAkhter if you don't trust it, you should have another backup (you should have that anyway). But *from what I can tell from here*, it should be fine.